# mp4 file upload issue in multer of node.js

Tags: node.js, express, ffmpeg, multer

I'm trying to upload mp4 file by using multer in node.js

(View)VideoUploadPage.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";


function VideoUploadPage() {

const onDrop = (files) => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    const config = {
      header: { "content-type": "multipart/form-data" },
    };
    formData.append("file", files[0]);
    console.log(files);

    Axios.post("/api/video/uploadfiles", formData, config).then((response) => {
      if (response.data.success) {
        console.log(response.data);
      } else {
        alert("비디오 업로드를 실패 했습니다.");
      }
    });
  };

}
```

(Server)

video.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");
const ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");



let storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "uploads/");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, `${Date.now()}_${file.originalname}`);
  },
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    const ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
    if (ext !== ".mp4") {
      return cb(res.status(400).end("only mp4 is allowed"), false);
    }
    cb(null, true);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single("file");

router.post("/uploadfiles", (req, res) => {
  upload(req, res, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.json({ success: false, err });
    }
    return res.json({
      success: true,
      url: res.req.file.path,
      fileName: res.req.file.filename,
    });
  });
});
```

At the video.js destination: (req, file, cb) => {
cb(null, "uploads/")
} <----- I can check which file is going to upload with console.log(response.data), but there is no mp4 file in the "uploads" folder.

When I changed "uploads/" to my local directory path, mp4 file is on the uploads folder ....

ex: "C://~~~/uploads"

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

use path.resolve('./uploads') to resolve a sequence of path-segments to an absolute path.

```
let storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: (req, file, cb) => {
cb(null, path.resolve('./uploads'); // path of the upload folder
},
filename: (req, file, cb) => {
cb(null, `${Date.now()}_${file.originalname}`);
},
fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
const ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
if (ext !== ".mp4") {
  return cb(res.status(400).end("only mp4 is allowed"), false);
}
cb(null, true);
},
});
```

Comment: I've already tried it but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can use path.resolve(process.cwd() + 'path till upload folder');

for eg:
path.resolve(process.cwd() + '/uploads');

Comment: It doesn't work too. I'm trying it different ways

Comment: "../uploads" <-- this works and I'm trying to find why that's works

Comment: At my end the above solution is working. You may have given the wrong path of upload folder. That's why it's not working for  you I guess.

Comment: Actually It's like a tutorial thing. I searched other people done about this, but exactly same code